# Sort array according to first array

Tags: php, sorting

I have this array `$arr1`

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  [col1]
    [1] =>  [col2]
    [2] =>  [col3]
)
```

I have another array `$arr2` as

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [col3] => data1
            [col2] => data2
            [col1] => data3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [col2] => data1
            [col3] => data2
            [col1] => data3
        )
)
```

I need to sort this `$arr2` keys as `col1, col2` and `col3` like as it is on `$arr1`.

I tried with `array_multisort($arr1,$arr2)` and the other way. Nothing worked. any help on this ?

Comment: I think that you'll have to write your own sorting function, but i'm curious to know if there are better solutions

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: all basic ways to sort arrays and data in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/reference-all-basic-ways-to-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with uksort and a closure (PHP 5.3+)

```
foreach($arr2 as &$array){
    uksort($array,function($a,$b) use ($arr1){
        return array_search($a, $arr1) - array_search($b, $arr1);
    });
}
```

Comment: your algorithm has `n*n*n*log(n)` complexity. n is the length of first array.

Answer (score 2):

Using loop.

```
$keys = array_values($arr1);
$out = array();
foreach($arr2 as $ar){
    $outar = array();
    foreach($keys as $k){
        if(isset($ar[$k])){
            $outar[$k]=$ar[$k];
        }
    }
    $out[]=$outar;
}
```

The output array will be held in `$out`. See [**ideone**](http://ideone.com/8h66oi).

Comment: There is no foreach..in loop in php. It should be foreach..as

Comment: @smm right you are. Using too much python these days. Forgetting PHP. Added a ideone link that shows it works.

Comment: yours is considerably more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ( $arr2 as $k => &$arr ) {
    ksort($arr);
}
print_r($arr2);
```

Use [ksort](http://php.net/ksort) with a foreach loop with value passed by reference.

Comment: I need to sort $arr2 not $arr1.

Comment: [`ksort`](http://php.net/manual/function.ksort.php) like any other *in-place* sorts in php will return a boolean indicating the success. Thus you're overwriting `$arr`.

Comment: and $arr2 needs to be ordered using information coming from $arr1

Comment: @Prashanth, I don't see any comparison with $arr1 ?

Answer (score 0):

if first array values are **exactly** the same as indexes in second one, try

```
$resarr = array();
foreach ($arr2 as $somearr) {
    $i = 0;
    $newarr = array();
    foreach ($somearr as $value) {
        $newarr[$arr1[$i]] = $value;
        $i++;
    }
    $resarr[] = $newarr;
}
$arr1 = $resarr;
```